# Как исключить границу (border) из ширины ячеек таблицы (td)?

Tags: html, css

Проще говоря мне нужно чтобы все жёлтые участки были одинаковы по ширине. Не понятно почему граница вообще включается в ширину ячеек.

https://jsfiddle.net/bds1w49n/2/

```css
table {
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    td {
      height: 50px;
      width: 10%;
      background: yellow;
      border-right: 10px solid gray;
      padding: 0;
    }
    td:last-child {
      border-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто нужно добавить один стиль:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Вот этот */
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bds1w49n/3/